# Is anything wrong with this approach to PCA?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

I'm working on an implementation of PCA that works on very large data sets.

Based on my understanding of the algorithm, the first step is to do an [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of the input `m x n` matrix, `X`. This SVD looks like X = WΣV<sup>T</sup>. The "interesting" output `Y` of this process -- [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Details), "The PCA transformation that preserves dimensionality (that is, gives the same number of principal components as original variables)" -- is given by the following equation:

[image: equation]

Based on my reading, if I can compute the `W` component of the SVD, then I can compute Y as:

[image: equation]

The upshot here is that I'd only have to compute `W`. In terms of computational and memory complexity, this approach is significantly more efficient because the only matrix above and beyond the initial data set I'd have to load has size `m x m`, which (at least in my case) is much smaller than `V`, which would be `n x n`.

Is there some reason why this derivation won't work that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Make sure you center and scale the data first!

Comment: That is correct, but how are you going to compute $W$ without computing everything else? What you should use is an "economy size" SVD that does not return those $n-m$ columns of $V$ that are filled with zeros. Then you don't have a problem. See point 10 in my answer here: [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282)