# Which SVD matrix do we use for cosine similarity

Tags: svd, latent-semantic-analysis, cosine-distance

In Latent Semantic Analysis, we get 3 matrices from the singular value decomposition (SVD), but I am confused - which matrix do we use for cosine similarity?

Comment: I do not vote this to close because for me it is very clear what the OP is asking. Having said that, I would suggest to the OP to actually write out what LSA is doing. I am pretty certain he will be able to answer his own question immediately afterwards; in particular he wants to examine the relation between PCA and SVD.

Comment: This question may also be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca