# How is PCA applied to new data?

Tags: pca, intuition, eigenvalues

I understand the basic intuition behind PCA: reducing the dimensionality of data by finding the eigenvectors along which there is most variance in the data, and projecting the data along these eigenvectors (the principal components).

What I don't understand is the following:

- **How are the eigenvectors found?** A standard eigenvector equation is given by $Av=\lambda v$, where $\lambda$ and $v$ are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors respectively. So what is the $A$ matrix - the data itself, or the covariance matrix of the data... or something else? (If the data matrix isnt square then this equation doesn't hold.)
- **Once PCA has been performed / trained on a data set, can it be applied to reduce the dimensionality of new unseen data?** For this to be true, I suppose a mapping would need to be output by PCA, and this mapping could be applied to the new data, say in the form of matrix multiplication.

  1. **What are the outputs of PCA?**
  2. **How are the outputs applied to new data, if at all?**

Comment: Q1: $A$ is the covariance matrix. Q2: you multiply your new data with $v$.

Comment: Aren't there multiple $v$'s? How would I multiply my new data by $v$ - which $v$?

Comment: Well if you want 2 PCs, then you take two eigenvectors corresponding to the two largest eigenvalues, and then multiply with those. Usually you have them stacked in a matrix V as columns, and can multiply your data directly with XV.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210666/rotating-a-new-matrix-into-the-same-basis-as-another-using-svd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer each question:

- $A$ is indeed the covariance matrix (so $X^TX$ assuming $X$ is standardized)
- The output of PCA is 3 things: the vector of column means $\mu$ of $X$, the vector of column stddevs $\sigma$ of $X$ and the rotation matrix $R = [v_1 ... v_p]$. Therefore, for a new sample row $x_0^T$, to compute its projection onto Principal Component Space, you have to standardize and rotate, that is $((x_0 - \mu) / \sigma)^T R$, which will yield a row vector with $x_0$ in PC coordinates. Please note that here I'm dividing by $\sigma$ elementwise.