# Principal Component Analysis PCA Terms and relationships: eigenvalues, eigenvectors, loadings, score matrix, and SVD

Tags: pca, svd, eigenvalues

I've read many websites, blogs, pdfs on this top but struggle to put the picture together in simple math terms, that explains how some of the terms relate to each other / are computed.

Let's assume that we use Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) to solve the PCA problem with input matrix $X$, assuming $X$ has zero mean and unit variance, the SVD of $X$:

$X = USV^{T}$

Now, $S$ is the vector of **eigenvalues**, sorted in decreasing order.

Can someone please explain, in math terms, how are the following terms defined?

- e.g. Explained variance ratios = $\frac{S}{sum(S)}$
- PCA Loadings == eigenvector of $X^{T}X$ == $V$?
- Score matrix $T$, $T == U * Diag(S) == XV$?
- Actual PCA components = eigenvectors of $X$?
- Eigenvectors, can you get them from the SVD results?

Comment: I think I found what I am looking for in this amazing answer {http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca} !!

Comment: If you  found everything you want, then perhaps this question should be closed as a duplicate? If there is anything you wanted but didn't find, it would be better to refocus this question on those elements alone, to avoid duplication :)

Comment: thanks, i closed this, let me think about this a bit more and maybe come back with questions if needed.

Comment: @Will, feel free to ask for clarifications in my Q&A post about PCA/SVD, if anything remains unclear there.