# Is there a way to extract the topics and/or get the SVD matricies after using PCA on a document matrix?

Tags: pca, svd, topic-models

I'm comparing various topic modeling algorithms on a data set and I'm hoping to compare them via looking at the log-likelihood of held out documents. I'm using SKLearn and I can see that PCA allows for a log-likelihood score (it uses the interpretation in [this paper](http://www.miketipping.com/papers/met-mppca.pdf)). However, PCA doesn't allow me to easily figure out what the topics are.

In contrast, with LSA (via SVD) I can easily extract the topics by looking at the columns of U where 
$$
A= U\Sigma V^T
$$
So I'm wondering if there is a way to either: (1) go back and forth  between the two; (2) extract the topics from PCA; or (3) get a log-likelihood of new documents after SVD?

I looked for answers here and I saw [this:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca) but I'm not able to use it derive an equation to go from the PCA to the SVD or vice-versa.

Alternatively, could I just calcuatle the SVD and PCA of the matrix and use the SVD to get the features and PCA to get the log-likelihood (i.e. would they correspond to each other)?