# How to obtain covariance matrix eigenvalues from singular values?

Tags: pca, covariance-matrix, svd, eigenvalues

I would like to implement closed form of PPCA ([Bishop, Tipping, 1999, Appendix A](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/courses/fall2010/Bishop_Tipping_1999_Probabilistic_PCA.pdf)). In this paper they calculate $W$ in formula `(15)`:

$W=U_q(K_q-\sigma^2I)^{1/2}R$

where $K_q$ is a matrix from eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of covariance matrix as defined in formula `(5)`.

On one hand I [read here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283/42357), that it is possible to calculate eigenvalues with

$\lambda_i = \frac{s_i^2}{n-1}$

Is it true, that principal values depend on number of samples $n$?

On other hand I found python implementation of closed `PPCA` on github, [function `__fit_ml`](https://github.com/cangermueller/ppca/blob/8b9a0f2b1eb0fc92f2c9a2176ca2347e90b30f90/src/pca/ppca.py#L86), where it is written

```
    mu = np.mean(self.y, 1)[:, np.newaxis]
    [u, s, v] = np.linalg.svd(self.y - mu)
    ...
    else:
        ss = s[:self.q]
    ss = np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, ss**2 - self.prior_sigma))
    w = u[:, :self.q].dot(np.diag(ss))
```

where author is apparently calculating with

$\lambda_i = s_i^2$

which is completely different.

**UPDATE**

Here $s_i$ is diagonal element of singular values matrix.

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried numeric example

```
X = np.float64(np.array([
    [-1, -1],
    [-2, -1],
    [-3, -2],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 2]]))

n_samples = np.shape(X)[0]

X -= np.mean(X, axis=0)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)

cov_matrix = np.dot(X.T, X) / n_samples

singularvalues = pca.singular_values_

for i in range(len(pca.components_)):
    eigenvector = pca.components_[i]
    eigenvalue = np.dot(eigenvector.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, eigenvector))
    singularvalue = singularvalues[i]
    eigenvalue2 = singularvalue**2 / n_samples
    print("%f\t%f;\t%f" % (eigenvalue, singularvalue, eigenvalue2))
```

output

```
6.616286    6.300612;   6.616286
0.050381    0.549804;   0.050381
```

and found that answer depends on covariance matrix normalization.

**UPDATE 3**

In the other hand it is written in Python's [SVD documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html):

> The rows of v are the eigenvectors of a.H a. The columns of u are the
>   eigenvectors of a a.H. For row i in v and column i in u, the
>   corresponding eigenvalue is s[i]**2.

**UPDATE 4**

Ah, sure, a.H a is "scatter matrix", i.e. covariance matrix w/o normalization.

Comment: In your reference at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282 you have misunderstood what $S$ is: it is not a covariance matrix.  It is the singular part of the model matrix.

Comment: I was using notation from the paper. I see that `S` means different things in these 2 sources.

Comment: Covariance matrix has $1/n$ or $1/(n-1)$ factor right in the definition, see formula 5 in the linked paper. SVD does not. So clearly the formula has to be $\lambda = s^2/n$ or $s^2/(n-1)$ depending on whether one is using Bessel's correction. I don't know what is going on in the `__fit_ml` code, but $\lambda=s^2$ cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: @amoeba what if $S$ was defined without $1/N$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Covariance already has a definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance. Do you mean what if $S$ were NOT a covariance matrix, but a scatter matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_matrix)? Well, eigenvalues of the scatter matrix are of course $s^2$.

Comment: @amoeba I didn't say "covariance" in the question, I said $S$.

Comment: OK, eigenvalues of the scatter matrix are of course $s^2$. (I added this to my previous comment.)

Comment: @amoeba sure, but I am trying to find an origins of possible error; what if somebody mixed covariance and scatter matrices (as you said)?

Comment: I don't know if it's really an error, maybe this github code has 1/n normalization done in some other place. In any case, your main question seems to be resolved by now, isn't it?

Comment: @amoeba yes, true