# Intuitions behind Singular Value Decomposing generalizing eigen decomposition

Tags: svd, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

Let M be mxn matrix then SVD of M will be UXW^* (sorry for X, assume summation). Then how does it generalizes eigen decomposition ? Since eigen decomposition is possible for nxn matrix and that are non-symmetric.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)

Comment: @DavideND thank you, I think I got it