# PCR after PCA with mixed data - how to extract/export the PCs as new variables in R?

Tags: regression, pca, mixed-type-data

As the title/question implies I ran a PCA with mixed data, i.e. categorical and numeric, in R, once with the "FactoMineR" and "factoextra" packages (analysis version 1) and once with the "PCAmixdata" package (analysis version 2) (just to compare both approaches, out of curiosity).

The original dataset consists of 184 variables/953 samples and the idea behind the PCA was to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset in order to gain less but more informative components (variables). This all worked and after both analysis versions it seems that the first 5 components/dimension are sound (largest eigenvalues and visual inspection of the scree plot). Now I would like to use these 5 PCs as predictor variables in a subsequent (principal component) regression. **And this is where I'm stuck.** *I don't know how to extract/export the PCs into new predictor variables so that each of the 953 subjects has a value in each of the 5 dimensions; I don't know which part of the output holds the information I need, or if further manual calculations will be necessary before I can extract the PC variables. If so, I wouldn't know the formula.*

FYI: The output for both analysis versions produces eigenvalues of the dimensions, "coordinates", "Cos2" (-> quality of representation of a variable through a PC) and "contributions" (-> contributions (in percentage) of the variables to the principal components) for both the variables and individuals (samples). With the "PCAmixdata" package (analysis version 2) one can also examine the "squared loadings" and the "coefficents of the linear combinations defining the PC" for the variables only.

I am aware of the pcr() function of the "pls" package but it doesn't seem to work since it inherently performs a PCA first and regular PCAs - to my knowledge - cannot use categorical data.

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are almost similar, if you run a pca using FactoMineR, you need the principal component score and they are stored under `$svd$U` because FactoMineR performs a pca using svd (you can see how they are [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)).

So for example using mtcars:

```
library(FactoMineR)
mpg = mtcars[,"mpg"]
pca.res = PCA(mtcars[,-1],graph=FALSE)
```

To get back the so called principal component scores, normally used in `prcomp` etc you do:

```
PCs = pca.res$svd$u %*% diag(pca.res$svd$d)
```

Because this is essentially multiplying the U matrix by its corresponding eigen value, for a regression this is not quite essential. However for complete sake, we can do:

```
PCs = PCs[,1:5]
```

Or you can do:

```
PCs = pca.res$ind$coord[,1:5]
```

followed by:

```
fit_PCs = lm(mpg ~ PCs)
```

If you use `pcr()` from pls:

```
fit_pls = pcr(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars,ncomp=5,
validation="none",scale=TRUE,center=TRUE)
```

The fitted values for 5 components are in:

```
fitted(fit_pls)[,,5]
```

So we check the fitted values from both:

```
plot(fitted(fit_pls)[,,5],fitted(fit_PCs),xlab="pls_5comp",ylab="PCA+lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much for the quick reply! This is extremely helpful, I could almost cry. 
Do I understand it correctly then that the principle component scores are - independent from what type of function I use - the scores I always have to look for and use when fitting the PCs as new variables in a subsequent regression?
Do you know by any chance where the scores are stored when applying the PCAmixdata package?
And if I may ask one last question concerning you comment on the pcr() function: Is it possible to use the function on _mixed data_ in that case??

Comment: yes you look for the scores / components basically, to fit a new regression. I am not familiar with PCAmixdata, I think you need to find where this matrix is stored. Not so familiar with that package unfortunately

Comment: quickly looking at the package vignette it should be res.pcamix$ind$coord, cos it says  ‘$coord’: factor coordinates (scores) of the individuals, again, i am not familiar with this so you should double check it

Comment: When I run res.pcamix$ind$coord for the pcamixdata package I get the same values as in running pca.res$ind$coord with FactoMineR. I suppose the values should however be identical to the output of pca.res$svd$U?

Comment: Browsing the factoMineR FAQ side there is an entry which says: 

"Where do I find scores [and loadings] in res.pca?
-> Scores (i.e. principal coordinates) are in:
res.pca$ind$coord
The variance of the individuals' coordinates for a dimension corresponds to the eigenvalue of this dimension."

Now I am just more confused about whether the scores are in scd§U or in ind§coord?

Comment: you can take the values from res.pca$ind$coord. I edit my answer to explain how it is derived.. sorry I did not realize they give you the values back

Comment: and you can see that if you use ```res.pca$svd$U``` or ```res.pca$ind$coord```, the results are the same

Comment: that's strange, when I use svd§U I get different values then with ind§coord. Why is this so complicated.

Comment: ok make sure you scale the data, and just use ```res.pca$ind$coord```, you want to do your pc regression, and i think you can proceed with that. by results i mean the fitted values from the regression

Comment: OK, I will try to find out how to manually scale the data, but I thiiiink the FAMD() of the FactoMineR package actually does that automatically, see: "FAMD is a principal component method dedicated to explore data with both continuous and categorical variables. It can be seen roughly as a mixed between PCA and MCA. More precisely, the continuous variables are scaled to unit variance and the categorical variables are transformed into a disjunctive data table (crisp coding) and then scaled using the specific scaling of MCA."