# Variability of K SVD components

Tags: variance, dimensionality-reduction, svd, eigenvalues

Let's say I have a SVD of a matrix $A = U \Sigma V^T$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, and I'm using top-k components corresponding to $\sigma_1, ..\sigma_k$, the k largest values on the diagonal of $\Sigma$. They are also square roots of k largest eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

I encountered the sum of $$\frac{\sum_1^k \sigma_i^2}{\sum_1^n \sigma_i^2}$$ being interpreted as "preserved variability". This makes sense if $A^T A$ were the variance - but it's not, not unless the mean along the rows of A is zero. What am I missing here? Is there an inherent assumption that SVD is only applied to "normalized" $A$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca) see amoeba's answer

Comment: sort of! it opens with "Let us assume that it is centered" :) If that is indeed the default assumption always, I guess the answer to my question is "$A$ is assumed to be centered"

Comment: see #5 in amoeba's summary

Comment: do you know if any useful interpretation exists if A is not centered?

Comment: interpretation of what?

Comment: $\frac{\sum_1^k \sigma_i^2}{\sum_1^n \sigma_i^2}$

Comment: I'm going to ask that as a separate question - thanks for this :)