# Meaning of PCA-based distances

Tags: pca, distance

Given that principal components analysis (PCA) have been performed on a dataset, the question is what does the distances between the coordinates of the data points in the transformed (PCA) space mean?  For instance, if Euclidean distance is calculated between point A and point B on the PCA coordinates is this perhaps equivalent to Mahalanobis distance between point A and point B with the original coordinates?

NOTE: assuming that the data is scaled as part of the PCA analysis.  The code in R to perform the PCA step would look like this (where `df` is the dataframe containing the original records)

`pca <- prcomp(df, scale=TRUE)`

Comment: depending on how you applied PCA (corr or cov) the distances can correspond to Mahalanobis distance

Comment: PCA on correlation (the data is scaled)

Comment: I think all of the facts you need to demonstrate this relationship are in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca -- the rest is just substitutions and algebra.