# Find first Principal Component (and loading) using a fast iterative algorithm without covariance matrix

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, eigenvalues, julia

I have a matrix $X$ and I would like to find its first principal component and the corresponding loadings. I would like to do this without computing the covariance matrix of $X$. How can I do so?

This is the standard version, which uses the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix.

```
using LinearAlgebra: eigen
using Statistics: mean

function find_principal_component(X)
    n = size(X, 1)
    B = X .- mapslices(mean, X, dims=[1])     # Center columns of X
    evalues, V = eigen(B'B / (n - 1))         # EigenDecomposition of Covariance Matrix     
    PC = V[:, argmax(evalues)]                # Grab principal component and compute loading
    return B * PC, PC
end
```

Alternatively, one could use the power method, which still uses the covariance matrix

```
function power_method(X, niter=50)
    pc = randn(size(X, 2))
    pc /= norm(pc)
    M = X'X
    for i in 1:niter
        pc = M * pc
        pc /= norm(pc)
    end
    return X * pc, pc
end
```

I would like something like the power method, but without needing to compute the covariance matrix, which can be quite costly.

## Possible solution

I noticed something interesting. Let $r_t$ be the principal component vector at time $t$. The idea of the power method is to start with a random $r_t$ and multiply it by $X^\top X$ many times to stretch it towards the principal component. In other words
$$
r_{t+1} = X^\top X r_t
$$
Once we have the principal component $r_t$ then the loadings are simply
$$
\ell_t = X r_t
$$
This means we can write
$$
r_{t+1} = X^\top \ell_t
$$
One could therefore start with $r_t$ and $\ell_t$ initialized randomly and then do
$$
\begin{align}
r_{t+1} &= \widehat{X^\top \ell_t} \\
\ell_{t+1} &= X r_{t+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is your proposed solution an answer to your question? Your method involves computing a product with X’X at each iteration, which is a scalar multiple of the covariance.  I thought you wanted to avoid forming the covariance matrix.

Comment: @Sycorax my proposed solution is just an idea I had but it doesn't really fit my criteria, as you explained. I just noticed that one could do two matrix-vector multiplications rather than one large matrix-matrix multiplication

Comment: Just use truncated SVD: it already exists in Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/TSVD.jl

Comment: @Physics_Student but certainly doing one matrix-vector product would be better than doing two, right?

Comment: Literature on this should be around what is called "Lanczos Bidiagonalization" methods. You might want to invest time to reimplement it just so you understand what it does.

Comment: @Sycorax yes, I was being an idiot. I guess I am just trying to find a way to do this that would be fast for a very large $X$

Comment: Finding structure with randomness: Stochastic algorithms for constructing approximate matrix decompositions Halko, et al., 2009 (arXiv:909) https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf

Comment: +1. Fun paper. I don't remember much about it, but I remember having fun reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is mean-centered (you have subtracted the mean of each column) with the columns storing the features and the rows storing the observations. PCA is the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix $\Sigma = \frac{1}{n-1}X^T X$.

There is a deep relationship between PCA and SVD. In fact, you can use SVD to compute PCA. See: [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)

SVD does not require forming $\Sigma$, and you can use power iteration to compute the singular vector to the largest singular value from $X$ directly. Note that this will work best if the largest singular value is much larger than all other singular values.

This is simply a naive approach using tools that you've already outlined. I'm sure there are better ones, perhaps exploiting specific knowledge about $X$.